# How to cancel a change made to a projectedValue

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

So I have a view that allows a user to update a `CoreData` property.

They then have the option to *cancel* or *save*

[image: 2 Buttons for saving or deleting]

The `TextField` is linked with the `projectedValue` of a `CoreData` class

`TextField("New Value", text: $coreDataClass.value)`

Its very nice that CoreData has been linked with Combine so that we can attach `$` to get the two-way binding feature. However on this particular view is causing me some problems because if a user hits cancel after inserting **any** value then the value persists even after the view is dismissed.

How would I cancel the change if the user hits cancel... I thought using a `lazy var` would be perfect since its only read once but that didn't work. I thought about using a class to capture the initial value and then use it in the `cancel` method but that did not work either.

Any guidance on the issue would be greatly appreciated!

**Answer for question in comment** *Unrelated*

```
import SwiftUI

extension Text {
    func buttonView(type: ButtonType) -> some View {
        
        func selectColor(type: ButtonType) -> Color {
            switch type {
            case .default:
                return .blue
            case .destructive:
                return .red
            case .utility:
                return .purple
            }
        }

       return self.bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .background(selectColor(type: type))
            .cornerRadius(8)
        
    }
}

enum ButtonType {
    case `default`
    case destructive
    case utility
}
```

Comment: You'll have to update some local `@State` property as a temporary storage, and on `save` assign it to core data

Comment: You should show your code where you are interacting with Core Data. Core Data will only save the changes when you commit them.

Comment: A side question, I like your Button size, are you using a custom size or there is a standard size that you used for this Buttons, also same for Color and Font?

Comment: @swiftPunk it’s an extension on Text, the only trick is the padding. Give it .padding(.horizontal) and .padding(.vertical, 8) just limiting the vertical cushioning

Comment: yes I know all, but what are the correct numbers? do we have standardised numbers? your Button size is look like apple size

Comment: @swiftPunk I posted the full code in the main question, see the original post, I think there is a way to better code the vertical padding instead of hard coding but haven't played around with that too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, when you edit CoreData field, it's not getting saved to the database until you run `viewContext.save()`.

In case you need to revert changes there's another one: `viewContext.rollback()`

But note, that it'll discard all changes made for all objects since the last save. So if you have many changes and wanna discard only a single one, you need to do it manually: in the init fill @State value with a value from your object field, and on Save write @State to your object field.